# How to make call directly without using calling intent?

Tags: android, phone-call

Can I make a call directly without calling dial intent?

I want to use this calling way to create a call manager.

What are some different ways of making a call?

Comment: That is not possible from an SDK application.You have to use Intent.ACTION_CALL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you have to use the `Intent.ACTION_CALL`. That's the only way:

```
Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
dialIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:000000"));
startActivity(dialIntent);
```

Comment: I told you Intent.ACTION_CALL is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge this is not possible from an SDK application.
You have to use `Intent.ACTION_CALL.` for making call..